# How to create factory in laravel with modules?

Tags: laravel

I installed  `composer require nwidart/laravel-modules` package in my project.

I created Transaction modules and I want to create a factory, How to use it?

```
php artisan module:make-factory TransactionFactory Transaction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should create a factory:

```
php artisan module:make-factory FactoryName Blog
```

Second, load your factory to the `provider.stub` ([provider.stub](https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules/blob/master/src/Commands/stubs/scaffold/provider.stub#L97))

Third, use this command:
`php artisan module:seed`